# How to make CSS animation to do vice versa after being completed?

Tags: css, css-animations

The code below is a part of my code :

```
.myBox:hover::after {
   animation-name: underline;
   animation-duration: 350ms;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes underline {
   from { width: 0; }
   to { width: 100%; }
}
```

It works nicley, but I want to do it vice versa when animation completed, I mean when it finished then `width` should be 0 again, In fact for this part I want to do it when my element is not hovered. Which property can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [alternate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction) and run [2 iterations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) of the animation:

```css
.box {
   height:200px;
   background:red;
   animation: underline 500ms alternate 2 forwards;
}

@keyframes underline {
   from { width: 0; }
   to { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Or consider the use of [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) if you want the effect on hover:

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  width: 0;
  transition: 500ms;
}

body:hover .box {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple values for animations rather then `from` and `to` using percentage:

```
@keyframes underline {
    0%, 100% { width: 0; }
    50% { width: 100%; }
}
```

More detailed information can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/).

Answer (score -1):

```
.myBox:hover::after {
   animation-name: underline infinite;
   animation-duration: 350ms;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes underline {
   from { width: 0; }
   to { width: 100%; }
}
```

You infinite for this